# UISegmentedController - Change segments to images

Tags: objective-c, image, uisegmentedcontrol

So basically, I would like to create a segmented controller out of four images.

!!! Images are: segment1_unselected , segment1_selected, segment2_unselected, segment2_selected.

I've read numerous tutorials about doing it if you have: segment background selected, 
segment background unselected, segment middle, left selected, right unselected, segment middle, left unselected, right selected, segment middle, both left & right selected, segment middle, both left & right unselected, but I don't have those. (I assume it's possible to do it with the 4 images I have since my teacher provided me with these images).

Now I've managed to add the images with, but then I don't know how to add the selected images.

```
UISegmentedControl * segmentedCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 130, 294, 34)];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr1_btneveryone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr1_btnfriends"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr1_btneveryone1"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr1_btnfriends"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
```

Edit: Well I'm kinda stupid... What I did was I wrote the "changing of the image (aka selecting a segment) myself by creating an action to ValueChanged, then using the setImage:forSegmentAtIndex: I've changed the images around. I just thought there was some built in method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like 
[HMSegmentedControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hmsegmentedcontrol), or [AKSegmentedControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aksegmentedcontrol).

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment, hence posting here.

You can use the appearance protocol, to change the background images. Some sample code:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toggle_blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toggle_grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Not quite. setBackgroundImage sets an image to the WHOLE segmented controller (one image for all segments, usually stretched), while I would've needed one image for segment1, another one for segment2. But I've wrote it myself, with adding an action to ValueChanged on the segmented control.